# code amendment so it will now open an xlsm file

Tags: excel, vba

My current code opens the XLS file perfectly but we now receive the files in xlsm format. I have tried to simply change the code from .xls to .XLSM but it reports that the file cannot be found.

Here is the current code:

```
Sub CopyRangeToAnotherSheet()
Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim wbThis As Workbook

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
End With

Set wbThis = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbThis = Workbooks.Open(Range("Z1") & Range("AA1") & ".xls")
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:m10000").Copy

Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook
wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").PasteSpecial
Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets("sheet1").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
wbThis.Close
 Sheets("Menu Tab").Activate
End Sub
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: So `Range("Z1") & Range("AA1") & ".xlsm"` would generate the correct new filename? If you're unsure, try using [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to watch for exactly what Excel is trying to open. (Might be worth doing that anyway.) And it also might be worth resaving as xlsx and change the filename here to xlsx to rule out the macros affecting this, or resave as .xls and check the existing code still works.

Comment: Can you upload your file somewhere that it can be checked? On the other hand the code you have provided can easily be recorded again. Recording it for the new file type after that you just have to change few things and it will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try catching the error and trying the new extension:

```
Sub CopyRangeToAnotherSheet()
Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim wbThis As Workbook

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
End With

Set wbThis = ActiveWorkbook
On Error Goto open_xlsm
Set wbThis = Workbooks.Open(Range("Z1") & Range("AA1") & ".xls")
On Error Goto 0  ' resume normal error "handling"
Goto open_done
open_xlsm:
On Error Goto 0
Set wbThis = Workbooks.Open(Range("Z1") & Range("AA1") & ".xlsm")    
open_done:
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:m10000").Copy

Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook
wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").PasteSpecial
Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets("sheet1").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
wbThis.Close
 Sheets("Menu Tab").Activate
End Sub
```

This will check for the files `foo.xsl` and `foo.xslm`, in that order.